# Strongly typed dataset Adapter.Update not inserting row

Tags: c#

I have the following code which (according to a [guide](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/15/435498.aspx)) should insert a record into my strongly typed dataset and in turn my database.  However, the record is not entered into the database but is correctly entered into the dataset.  Am I missing a command?

```
    using (Dataset1TableAdapters.AddressTableAdapter addressAdapter = new Dataset1TableAdapters.AddressTableAdapter())
{
    using (Dataset1.AddressDataTable addresses = new Dataset1.AddressDataTable()) 
    {
        // Create a new address.
        Dataset1.AddressRow address = addresses.NewAddressRow();

        // Set some data.
        address.Address1 = "test1";
        address.Address2 = "test2";
        address.Address3 = "test3";
        address.UserID = 1;

        // Add new address to address table.
        addresses.AddAddressRow(address);

        // Update the database with all the changes.
        addressAdapter.Update(addresses);
    }
}
```

Cheers,
Paul.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a `CommandBuilder` Object associates with your adapter

Answer (score 1):

Please call `addresses.AcceptChanges()` before calling update command and let me know if this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your connection object set correctly?  A typed dataset will default its connection based upon configuration.  You can also specify a connection object upon creation of a TableAdapter.

Comment: Hi.  The connection object is correct.  I can select data in the database without problems.